# Python: Won't Connect to Server

Tags: python, networking, irc

I'm not able to connect to the server it will print out

"Connecting to port..." then it will just say "Sockets timed out."

My program is due tomorrow and it'd  be nice to have this actually work.

EDITED CODE: **Now it will only use Connecting to Port....**
nothing else printed.

```
import socket, string, time, random, re, urllib2, cookielib, smtplib, os

class Pibot: #main class
        def __init__(self):  #basic information to allow for the rest of the program to work.
            self.server= 'irc.evilzone.org'
            self.port = 6667
            self.botname= 'pibot'
            self.chan= 'test'
            self.owner = 'Josh.H'
            self.nick = "bawt"
            self.irc = None
            self.data = ''

    def iConnect(self): #trys to connect to the server and allows the user to see if it failed to connect.
            print ("Connecting to ports...")
            print self.data
            time.sleep(3)
            try:
                    self.irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                    self.irc.connect((self.server, self.port))

            except (socket.error, socket.herror, socket.gaierror):
                    print "Failed to connect to Ports"



    def iStart(self):
            #Not guaranteed to send all your data, iisn't checking the return values
            #however this function iStart is used to send the NICK of the bot and the USER to the server through particle data
            #it then auto joins the channel
            #in future development I'd like to get accuainted with Twisted or IRCutils as they allow it to be quiet powerful and less buggy

            self.irc.send('NICK %s\r\n' % self.nick)
            self.irc.send("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % ("Ohlook", 'itsnotmy', 'Realname'))
            time.sleep(4)
            self.irc.send("JOIN #%s\r\n" % self.chan)
            self.data = self.irc.recv( 4096 ) 

    def MainLoop(self,iParse = 0): #MainLoop is used to make the commands executable ie !google !say etc;
            try:
                while True:
                    # This method sends a ping to the server and if it pings it will send a pong back
                    #in other clients they keep receiving till they have a complete line however mine does not as of right now
                    #The PING command is used to test the presence of an active client or
                    #server at the other end of the connection.  Servers send a PING
                    #message at regular intervals if no other activity detected coming
                    #from a connection.  If a connection fails to respond to a PING
                    #message within a set amount of time, that connection is closed. A
                    #PING message MAY be sent even if the connection is active.
                    #PONG message is a reply to PING message.  If parameter <server2> is
                    #given, this message will be forwarded to given target.  The <server>
                    #parameter is the name of the entity who has responded to PING message
                    #and generated this message.

                    self.data = self.irc.recv( 4096 )
                    if self.data.find ( 'PING' ) != -1:
                        self.irc.send(( "PONG %s \r\n" ) % (self.recv.split() [ 1 ])) #Possible overflow problem

                    if self.data.find( "!google" ) != -1:
                        #googles the search term and displays the first 5 results
                        #format = !google: <Search Term>
                        #One thing that I noticed is that it will print on a seperate line without the header
                        #In the next Update I would have fixed this.
                        fin = data.split(':')
                        if not fin:
                                irc.send("PRIVMSG #%s :syntax'^google :search term\r\n'" % chan)

                        else:
                            #In the next version to avoid overflow I will create another if statement and edit the search code
                            #However I am using what xgoogle has reccomended.
                                fin = fin[3].strip() 
                                gs = GoogleSearch(fin)
                                gs.results_per_page = 5
                                results = gs.get_results()
                                for result in results:
                                    irc.send("PRIVMSG #%s :%s\r\n" % (chan, result.url.encode("utf8")))

                    ###############################################################################################################################
                    #   No excpetion checking here, these functions can and will fail in time and in later versions will need to be edited.          
                    #   If hellboundhackers changes this code may break
                    #   This function takes a quote from the header of hellboundhackers
                    #   it first looks at the header of the USer agent then the header of the website (HBH) and reads it then prints
                    #   the quote when QUOTEM is recognized in the irc closes the connection to the wbesite and deletes the cookie
                    ###############################################################################################################################

                    if "QUOTEM" in self.data:
                        #Pulls a quote from HBH
                        cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
                        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
                        opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0'))
                        opener.addheaders.append( ('Referer', 'http://www.hellboundhackers.org/index.php') )
                        resp = opener.open('http://www.hellboundhackers.org/index.php')
                        r = resp.read()
                        resp.close()
                        del cj, opener
                        da = re.findall("Enter; width:70%;'>(.*)",r)
                        self.irc.send("PRIVMSG #%s :%s\r\n" % (chan, da[0])) # Note Possible overflow

                    if "!whoareyou" in self.data:
                        #bot info allows users on IRC to see which commands are currently working
                        self.irc.send("PRIVMSG #%s :I am %s, I was created By:%s \r\n" % (self.chan, self.nick,self.owner))
                        self.irc.send("PRIVMSG #%s :I was written in Python 27, and edited with IDLE\r\n" % self.chan)
                        self.irc.send("PRIVMSG #%s :The Classes used are socket, string, time, re, urllib2, cookielib\r\n" % self.chan)
                        self.irc.send("PRIVMSG #%s :As well as some functions from various other sources(supybot,twisted,xgoogle)\r\n" % self.chan)
                        self.irc.send("PRIVMSG #%s :type ^commands for a list of things I can do\r\n" % self.chan)
            except (socket.error, socket.timeout):
                    print "Sockets timed out."

bot = Pibot()
bot.iConnect()
bot.MainLoop()
```

Side Note: No errors present.
Greatly Appreciated. Also I am just learning so don't flame me. :(

EDIT2: I have fixed most of the problems and am now getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "L:\txtbot.py", line 119, in <module>
    bot.MainLoop()
  File "L:\txtbot.py", line 64, in MainLoop
    self.irc.send(( "PONG %s \r\n" ) % (self.recv.split() [ 1 ])) #Possible overflow problem
AttributeError: Pibot instance has no attribute 'recv'
```

Comment: Can you connect from the command line using `telnet irc.evilzone.org 6667`?

Comment: Do you mean within the code using the telnet function or just the server in general.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're never passing the connection information to the socket:

```
                self.irc = socket.socket()
```

I think it should be something like this:

```
                self.irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                self.irc.connect((self.server, self.port))
```

Comment: I had that initially but would socket.socket be the same (well I saw something like that in many irc skeletons.

EDIT: Okay I fixed it but now I'm getting 
  File "L:\txtbot.py", line 118, in <module>
    bot.iConnect()
  File "L:\txtbot.py", line 24, in iConnect
    elf.irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
NameError: global name 'elf' is not defined

I know the one is because its self but the other?

Comment: @21days: Could you put this in the question or somewhere else where it will be remotely readable, with the change to the code you made :)

Comment: You typed "elf" not "self". What do you mean "the other"? There's only one error message there.

Comment: Okay I fixed that let me post the new edited code. It's still not connecting.

Answer (score 0):

In `iConnect` you're just creating a socket, not connecting it to the server. You need to use [socket.create_connection](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection).
Also, lumping together socket.error and socket.timeout is not a good idea as it might be misleading when debugging. Also, you should print the error, not just a generic message. It will help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What do you mean, where would I create the connection?

Comment: socket.socket() just creates a socket, but it doesn't connect it. socket.create_connection() creates a socket and connects to the server. Look it up.

Comment: self.irc = socket.create_connection((self.server, self.port))


Still hasnt fixed the problem.

Comment: You should add a `print "Connected"` after `self.irc.connect` so you can see if it connected or not.

Comment: Yes I have done that etc etc; and now am getting:

  File "L:\txtbot.py", line 117, in <module>
    bot.iConnect()
  File "L:\txtbot.py", line 25, in iConnect
    self.server = socket.create_connection(((self.server,self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 551, in create_connection
    host, port = address
ValueError: too many values to unpack


I'm sorry about this just need this done...

Comment: "You should add a print "Connected" after self.irc.connect so you can see if it connected or not. "

I did that and now its connected but still not joining chan's or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `iStart` anywhere.  If I remember my IRC correctly, you need to send your nick information before it will send you any data back.

Comment: bot = Pibot()
bot.iConnect()
bot.iStart()
bot.MainLoop()

Comment: Yes I'm sorry but now it is and it seems the code that I'm having troubles with is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "L:\txtbot.py", line 119, in <module>
    bot.MainLoop()
  File "L:\txtbot.py", line 64, in MainLoop
    self.irc.send(( "PONG %s \r\n" ) % (self.recv.split() [ 1 ])) #Possible overflow problem
AttributeError: Pibot instance has no attribute 'recv'

Comment: `self` is your class.  `self.irc` is the actual socket.  You have various places in your code where you are either missing `self` or are missing `irc` it seems.

Comment: ugh.. where exactly do you mean.

Comment: Check every line that has `irc` to ensure `self` is before it.  Also check `self.irc` is before anything that has `send` or `recv`.  There are about 2 or 3 that I spotted in your MainLoop function.